# Jensen's inequality implications

Tags: functional-analysis

I am unable to understand implication of Jensens inequality.

If $||x||_r$ $\leq||x||_p$, 
and

if $1\leq p <r<\infty$ then

how does it imply $l^p\subset l^r$

I know I am missing some important clue. Request help

Comment: Comparison test?

Comment: Maybe you can start by explaining what $l^p\subset l^r$ means. Understanding the statement is necessary for explaining why it's true.